# iOS 10 Today extension can't read shared user defaults any more

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an application that implements Today extension. Till iOS10 it was working fine, but now I see that it can't read keys stored in shared NSuserDefaults.

My Host app code:

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedPrefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kSharedGroupIdentifier];
[sharedPrefs setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[sharedPrefs setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"test"];
[sharedPrefs synchronize];
```

My extension code:

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedPrefs  = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kSharedGroupIdentifier];
NSString *str = [sharedPrefs valueForKey:@"test"];
```

And str var is always nil in extension. I have set up my App Groups in Capabilities for both Host app and extension app, and I have checked it against the settings on Apple developer portal. It is all OK. Can anyone please help, is there something different that I must do?

**EDIT**
Another thing that I have noticed is that I have a red exclamation mark on: "Add the Add Groups entitlement to your entitlement file", and when I fix the issue, the exclamation mark goes away, but when I close and reopen project it is there again. I have recreated provisional profiles, but still the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the issues is that your Entitlements file is missing the relevant line.

To diagnose where the issue is, start with your build settings:

- Under `Code Signing Entitlements` there should be a file listed
- Open that file and ensure that it has the `App Groups` key with the value that matches your `kSharedGroupIdentifier`
- Ensure that the file is not marked read-only (this would potentially cause the "fix" to not work correctly)
- Verify that all of the following match:

  - kSharedGroupIdentifier in both apps
  - kSharedGroupIdentifier and the value in your entitlements file for `App Groups`

Next, we can narrow the issue down to the specific key or the entire preferences domain as follows:

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedPrefs  = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kSharedGroupIdentifier];
if (sharedPrefs == nil) {
  NSLog(@"Error loading shared user defaults!");
}
```

A nil value indicates that the suite name is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

**Rebooting** the mac solved the issue for me.

Apple [RNotes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html) WWDC Seed: Running multiple iOS simulators can cause NSUserDefaults to not work Running an iOS 8 or 9 simulator followed by an iOS 10 simulator will cause NSUserDefaults to stop working in the simulator. This can be worked around by rebooting the host Mac.

I hope it will helps you,

Thanks.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, btw, I the problem occurs on device as well. Another thing that I have noticed is that I have a red exclamation mark on: "Add the Add Groups entitlement to your entitlement file", and when I fix the issue, the  exclamation mark goes away, but when I close and reopen project it is there again. I have recreated provisional profiles, but still the same issue,